# How to enable access to the kernel config file through /proc/config.gz?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, compiling, configuration

I see this on the Internet:

```
General Setup  --->
    <*/M> Kernel .config support
        [*] Enable access to .config through /proc/config.gz
```

But can't understand what's that mean?

I have an arm-based board(NanoPi-M1 with Allwinner H3 sun8iw7p1 SoC) that has Debian Jessie OS, and I have no `config.gz` file in `/proc` directory. I only have `config-3.4.39-h3.new` file in `/boot` directory that it is an empty file!

I added `modules="configs"` in `/etc/modules` file and reboot my system but had no sense!

How can I access to kernel configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see this on the Internet:

It specifies the location in Linux's `menuconfig` from where you can enable `/proc/config.gz`. You must recompile the Linux kernel to do this. On an ARM-based board this may not be mainline Linux but a different tree specific to the SoC used on the ARM board.

So, the steps would be:

- Figure out which SoC you have on the board
- Figure out where to obtain the Linux kernel tree ported to that SoC
- Obtain and compile the Linux kernel, enabling the /proc/config.gz option
- Install modules, register the newly-compiled kernel with the bootloader, and reboot

Comment: Hi Daniel,
My board is NanoPi-m1 that has Allwinner H3 (sun8iw7p1) SoC.
Is there a strightforward and simple tutorial of doing it for new users?

Comment: +1. 3.4.39-h3 means it's probably a FriendlyARM NanoPi (as confirmed above by the OP while I was typing this!); at least the [BSP is available](https://github.com/friendlyarm/h3_lichee).

Comment: @Stephen: May you explain more?
what do I must do?

Comment: Or do what I did, ask the kernel vendor. I gave an hint in the Armbian forum for them to enable the feature. ;)